# Use SSIS to write in other CubeSystems than SSAS

Tags: ssis, ssas, cognos-tm1

I've got a project where I have different cube systems (esp.:Tm1, Infor PM 10, SSAS). Is there a way to fill these cubes with SSIS? The Connection SSIS-SSAS for sure is an easy one. But are there any approaches to write into other Cube Systems with SSIS? (Maybe an open source Interface?)

If not, what would be the best tools to use? At the Moment I only know Cubeware Importer, but that one is so slow - I definitely Need a faster one.

Comment: Most multi-dimensional systems are data-pull based because of their intricate aggregation mechanims rather than push systems.  With SSAS, you're calling process task, or XMLA to process your cube.  Other cube systems have similar abilities to process data - depends on which one you need to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Execute SQL task to send processing commands to the non-SSAS OLAP Servers.  I'm no expert in Tm1 or InforPM, but whatever their equivalent of SSAS's XMLA is can be sent by an SSIS package.